# Why does $digest run all the watches that have been registered on the scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I was wondering why $digest runs all the watches that have been registered on the scope, if you had multiple inputs with data coming from the scope in a view, why does AngularJS have to dirty check all the watches of the scope when for instance just one input field is bound to a label?

Comment: can you provide a code sample to supplement your question?

Comment: This question is more about how the framework works, just was wondering why you need to do a dirty check and loop through all the watches of a view when just one input field is bound to something else that's not affecting the rest of the UI.

Comment: You as the programmer have the full ability (and obligation) to limit what is in each scope through segmentation of controllers and directives. You can also unbind watches for scope variables when you'd like. Also, this question is not especially suitable for SO, unless it is secondary to a problem you're having that you can provide some code for http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It looks like the main reason why AngularJS is using dirty checking is because the models are just Plain Old JavaScript Objects (POJO). http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/#dirty_checking

Comment: How would it know something has changed (and therefore that it needs to update things in data binds) if it does not do the dirty checking on each digest cycle?

Comment: This blog explains the reason why dirty checking is needed when POJO is used: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html, the only way to avoid dirty checking is by using wrappers [accessors].

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not clairvoyant; it doesn't know what your watchers do except by checking their value. If something may have changed that could potentially mean that displayed data needs to be updated, Angular will check all your watchers. If something never needs to be checked, it shouldn't have a watcher.

Of course it's possible that you have something that only needs to be bound once and won't change after that, which means it doesn't have to be checked constantly. I'm not sure if there's a standard solution for that, but here is a [project on Github that provides one-time binding for Angular](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce).

Comment: Since Angular version 1.3 there is a standard solution for this. See http://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/